# JavaFX LineChart zooming is not precise

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to implement a zoom rectange for LineChart. Here is my code :

```
private void doZoom(Rectangle zoomRect, LineChart<Number, Number> chart) {
    Point2D zoomTopLeft = new Point2D(zoomRect.getX(), zoomRect.getY());
    Point2D zoomBottomRight = new Point2D(zoomRect.getX() + zoomRect.getWidth(), zoomRect.getY() + zoomRect.getHeight());

    NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) chart.getYAxis();
    NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
    yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

    var xAxisMaxBoundValuePoint = xAxis.sceneToLocal(zoomBottomRight);
    var xAxisMinBoundValuePoint = xAxis.sceneToLocal(zoomTopLeft);
    var xAxisScaleFactor = xAxis.getScale();

    xAxis.setLowerBound(xAxisMinBoundValuePoint.getX()/xAxisScaleFactor);
    xAxis.setUpperBound(xAxisMaxBoundValuePoint.getX()/xAxisScaleFactor);

    var yAxisMinBoundValuePoint = yAxis.sceneToLocal(zoomBottomRight);
    var yAxisMaxBoundValuePoint = yAxis.sceneToLocal(zoomTopLeft);

    var yAxisScaleFactor = yAxis.getScale();

    yAxis.setLowerBound(yAxisMinBoundValuePoint.getY()/yAxisScaleFactor);
    yAxis.setUpperBound(yAxisMaxBoundValuePoint.getY()/yAxisScaleFactor);

    zoomRect.setWidth(0);
    zoomRect.setHeight(0);
}
```

I see that xAxis limits are fine - the match zoom Rectange but yAxis are not precise. Upper bound is a little bit less and Lower bound is a little bit lower than expected. What is so special about it?

PS
I tried this https://gist.github.com/james-d/7252698 as an example but there seems to be a bug in case axis are not always positive...

Comment: That gist is very old; I think I would use a different approach if I were trying to do that now. Not tested, but try getting the bounds of the rectangle in the scene, using `zoomRect.localToScene(...)`. Then get the x-coordinates in the x-axis coordinate system using, e.g., `double minXDisplay = xAxis.sceneToLocal(new Point2D(minX, 0)).getX()`. And finally translate those to the x-axis data units using `xAxis.getValueForDisplay(minXDisplay)`. Similarly for the max value and the y-values.

Comment: Great ! Your approach works perfectly - I'll post an answer with a code snippet for someone else looking one day. Many many thanks to you :)

Comment: Just curious. Are you the author of https://github.com/kerner1000/javafx-chart-zooming?

Comment: @Sedrick Not me, no.

Comment: @James_D I thought maybe it was the OP. The method looked similar to the one in the linked program. Well, at least the name of the method.

Comment: @James_D  I just looked at your original Gist. Things look similar to your code. It's no issue though. Just my curiosity.

Comment: It’s not my repo also. I googled this repo while working under zooming feature for my javafx app. Everything worked ok except the case with negative axis. So i tried to rework it based on api doc. But of course the name of the method left the same ;).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to James_d, I've developed the following solution :

```
private void doZoom(Rectangle zoomRect, LineChart<Number, Number> chart) {
    Point2D zoomTopLeft = new Point2D(zoomRect.getX(), zoomRect.getY());
    Point2D zoomBottomRight = new Point2D(zoomRect.getX() + zoomRect.getWidth(),
            zoomRect.getY() + zoomRect.getHeight());

    var zoomTopLeftScene = zoomRect.localToScene(zoomTopLeft.getX(),zoomTopLeft.getY());
    var zoomBottomRightScene = zoomRect.localToScene(zoomBottomRight.getX(), zoomBottomRight.getY());

    NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) chart.getYAxis();
    NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
    yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

    var minXDisplay = xAxis.sceneToLocal(zoomTopLeftScene);
    var maxXDisplay = xAxis.sceneToLocal(zoomBottomRightScene);

    var xLowerBound = xAxis.getValueForDisplay(minXDisplay.getX());
    var xUpperBound = xAxis.getValueForDisplay(maxXDisplay.getX());

    xAxis.setLowerBound( xLowerBound.doubleValue() );
    xAxis.setUpperBound( xUpperBound.doubleValue() );

    var maxYDisplay = yAxis.sceneToLocal(zoomTopLeftScene);
    var minYDisplay = yAxis.sceneToLocal(zoomBottomRightScene);

    var yLowerBound = yAxis.getValueForDisplay(minYDisplay.getY());
    var yUpperBound = yAxis.getValueForDisplay(maxYDisplay.getY());

    yAxis.setLowerBound( yLowerBound.doubleValue() );
    yAxis.setUpperBound( yUpperBound.doubleValue() );

    zoomRect.setWidth(0);
    zoomRect.setHeight(0);
}
```

Comment: I think you can simplify slightly; there's no need for `new Point2D(zoomTopLeftScene.getX(), 0)`, etc; just use `zoomTopLeftScene` there.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks for review - updated my post